# call method on textbox if textbox is on a specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a method that is set dynamically to different textboxes in my form. But the problem is that i only want the method to work if i am on my view called riskscore.cshtml. It there a way? like a if(page == riskscore.cshtml){ do method} kind of code?

Comment: How would/should JavaScript ever know about something that only exists on the server? :)

Comment: i don't know... Maybe you can call the element and se if the elements page is riskscore or something?

Comment: Hm - you're saying that it's added to textboxes dynamically. Why don't you only attach that method to textboxes on riskscore.cshtml? Or can you not change the server / method attaching logic?

Comment: i use the "same" textbox on multiple pages. So i append the methods onkeyup before the page i loaded and all of the onkeyup methods will try to do their work every time the textbox is used. The problem is that when it tries to use this method on wrong page it wont found the neccessary elements that it need to run so it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript typically has no way of knowing if or when a particular view file was used server-side. It only knows the results that the view rendered.

You can wrap the contents of the view in say a `<div class="riskscore">`, then select textboxes within those:

```
$('.riskscore :text')...
```

You also mentioned in a comment that other elements won't exist without this view. You can use them as your condition, checking whether they exist:

```
if ($('.other-elements').length) {
    // do method
}
```

Replace `'.other-elements'` as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can test URLs in JavaScript:

```
if(/\/riskscore\.chtml$/.test(window.location.pathname)) {
  // You're on riskscore.chtml... Do something
}
```

Comment: He's using MVC, this means that the URL in the browser can be (and is by default) completely different than the file name on the server.

Comment: I don't get it to work.  My page is in views/home/riskscore. I changed riskscore to view/home/riskscore.cshtml but it did'nt work either :(

Comment: It's OK; just compare using `window.location.href` or other properties of `window.location`. For example, you can compare `/\/riskscore(\/|$)/.test(window.location.href)`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `window.location` to get the current location. or you can use `location.pathname` to current path.

[link here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location)

I think it will help

Comment: the window.location.pathname gives me "/" as answere? What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: @DanielGustafsson check with location.pathname

Comment: @DanielGustafsson if you are at homepage then it will return /